Exactly-once semantics in RDBMS
In the world of MQ (message queue) systems like Kafka, there are lots of discussions about "exactly-once" semantics. "Exactly-once" semantics can be applied to every distributed system, not only to MQ systems but also RDBMSs, but are less discussed. People are concerned with exactly-once semantics and struggle to ensure a message is delivered only once when they use MQ systems like Apache Kafka.
Is it as much of a concern for a RDBMS?
(The real-world possibility of exactly-once itself is out of the question.)
How can I assure that a RDBMS executes a query only once?
This might be guaranteed (even though it is imperfect) by transactions with ACID properties, WAL or anything else.
Why don't MQ systems utilize them to support exactly-once semantics?
For example, Apache Kafka supports exactly-once semantics under a cluster, when there are no side-effects.
Can exactly-once semantics be applied in a very simple situation like producer -> cluster or cluster -> consumer?
You can produce a message twice or consume a message twice when something goes wrong.

"by transaction with ACID properties" --- what if a transaction was committed successfully but then communication about that is lost? Then the action has been completed, yet you don't know about it.

Are you talking about using an RDMS as the consumer, or as the queue itself?

If your application has non-transactional side effects, I doubt you can guarantee exactly-once semantics for them.

Databases will do whatever you tell them to do, exactly once. You're maybe asking about exactly once semantics in your own application layer, independent of a (non distributed) database. Also this is vaguely an opinion question, with multiple questions in one, and will likely be closed, as discussion style questions are not appropriate for Stackoverflow.

@zerkms That is one of the points I was wondering, which means the RDBMS also can't guarantee the exactly-once semantics. So I mentioned that "even though it is imperfect" actually means I can't sure the semantic is guaranteed or not.

@AndyRay I was just wondering what makes people(maybe only me?) to believe that RDBMS is safer than MQs, like transactional outbox pattern (also I may be confused with this pattern)

"believe that RDBMS is safer than MQs" --- possibly because error handling with DB is easier: you can query it and see if your changes have been applied or not*

Kafka has retries in the producer. It's the consumer that explicitly needs configured to detect transaction markers and dedupe any events already written, so it's exactly once processing (assuming you also handle offsets correctly), not exactly once delivery

@chl I dont think there’s anything specific to relational databases here, I think the distinction is distributed systems. A distributed relational database  has all sorts of semantics to consider with replication and single/multi-leader, etc. maybe the misconception is relational databases aren’t usually distributed (sqllite is even single threaded!) so you perceive them as not having these issues?

There are also several possible concurrency models with relational database transactions, where even in a single database, with multiple clients, there are some insidious concurrency bugs, like “read after write” consistency issues. I also highly recommend the book “Designing Data Intensive Applications” which talks about this
